# Inserting a signature automatically into an Outlook Calendar meeting request

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, calendar, email-signature

Is there a way to automatically have a signature inserted into a Microsoft Outlook Calendar request, as one can do with emails?

Answer (score 1):

From everything that I've been reading it is not possible.  Why Microsoft has not added this functionality is beyond me.  It's so basic and they already have the format for the email.  All they would have to do is add a check box on the signature creation page so you can select where you want the signature to default.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with outlook VBA macros?

You can write a macro in `Application_ItemSend` function so that it will be triggered every time you hit send button.
In the macro, check if the item type is a calender request and if it is, just insert the signature.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have clicked "invite attendees" an option then appears in "insert" to insert a signature. This option does not show before you click "invite attendees"

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy alternative. Create a new signature that you need for meetings. When creating a new meeting go to `Insert`->`Signature` and select the signature created.

Answer (score 0):

I just clicked on the APPS icon along the top next to Scheduling Assistant and panel pops up on the right hand side of the page. Click + New Template, and I added a new template which contains my signature copied from my email and clicked SAVE. Then you just have to select that template and it will populate your message box. Hope that saves you some time trying to figure it out yourself like I just did.

Answer (score 0):

To insert the signature you most likely already use for Outlook Email Messages, into a Calendar invite:

When you create a new invite, go to "Insert", then "Signature".  It gives you the option to use an existing signature, or create a new one.

I don't see a way to permanently save that signature, but you can still add it to every appointment fairly easily using the steps I offered.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser and thanks for contributing! This same solution has already been posted quite some time ago by other users, though. [1](http://superuser.com/a/496962/348859), [2](http://superuser.com/a/287929/348859). If you find an answer you think is the best, you'll be able to upvote it once you have 15 reputation, which is not too hard if you stick around for a few days. That's a better option that posting it again as that can cause confusion for future readers.